# TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating a discord bot dashboard website with express and i've been getting this error but can seem to fix it: TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined. When I run the code everything is completely working but the error still pops up.

This is my entire page:

```
const router = express.Router();
const OAuthClient = require('disco-oauth');
const AuthClient = new OAuthClient(
    '732404499209256980',
    'bqX8W8RXQl-lqgbjxVqys7dlRcUzUZAk'
);
const inviteURL ='https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=732404499209256980&permissions=2147479255&scope=bot',
    loginURL = `https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=732404499209256980&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvalbot-testing.valblaze.repl.co%2Fauth&response_type=code&scope=identify%20guilds`;

AuthClient.setRedirect(`https://valbot-testing.valblaze.repl.co/auth`);
AuthClient.setScopes('identify', 'guilds');

router.use(async (req, res, next) => {
    const key = req.cookies.get('key');

  res.locals.user = await AuthClient.getUser(key);

  next();
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('home'));

router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
    res.render('dashboard/index');
});

router.get('/invite', (req, res) => res.redirect(inviteURL));
router.get('/login', (req, res) => res.redirect(loginURL));
router.get('/auth', async (req, res) => {
    const key = await AuthClient.getAccess(req.query.code);
    res.cookies.set('key', key);

    res.redirect('/dashboard');
});

router.get('*', (req, res) => res.render(`errors/404.pug`));

module.exports = router;
```

but this seems to be the code breaking it:

```
    const key = req.cookies.get('key');

  res.locals.user = await AuthClient.getUser(key);
```

whenever I call `await AuthClient.getUser(key)` it breaks and i've tried logging the key to the console it works fine just like a normal key.

Is there anything i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the cookie 'key' might not always be present, especially when you are not already logged in. For that reason you should protect the code this way:

```js
const key = req.cookies.get('key');
res.locals.user = key ? await AuthClient.getUser(key) : null;
```